Sample size estimation using G*Power
I am trying to calculate an a priori sample size using the G*Power for a project that I intend to do. I will collect reaction time data from two groups of participants across two time points (T1, T2). The experiment will be a simple non-verbal Stroop task with three experimental conditions (with emotional faces - happy, angry, neutral) and one control condition (no emotional faces). The groups will be compared at T1 and T2 and also within-group comparisons across the two time points. The groups will be compared at T1 and T2 and also within-group comparisons across the two time points.
How can I estimate the sample size for each group? Is G*Power capable of doing this estimation?
